# getObjectInBackgroundWithId: using pointer [ Parse ]

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

First i get the current user and the connected book to that user (It's a pointer to a book objectId). Then i want to find the book using the getobjectinBackgroundWithId method and then display the book name. When i change `getObjectInBackgroundWithId:storeUserID` to `getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"f4Dg92xC2"` it works perfect!

```
PFUser *currentuser = [PFUser currentUser];
storeUserID = currentuser[@"connectedBook"]; //Store book id in a string
NSLog(@"%@", storeUserID); // what i get <Book:f4Dg92xC2:(null)>


PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Book"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:storeUserID block:^(PFObject *books, NSError *error){
    PFObject *bookObject = books[@"bookName"];
    NSLog(@"bookName:%@", bookObject);
}];
```

when i run this, the NSLog with the book name, shows:

> Error: bad special key: objectId (Code: 102, Version: 1.2.20)
>   2014-09-17 23:28:56.529 MyApp[18977:90b] bookName:(null)

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment `//Store book id in a string` is incorrect. A pointer doesn't return the string object id, it returns the object itself. So you already have it and you don't need to call `getObjectInBackgroundWithId:`.

The log `<Book:f4Dg92xC2:(null)>` even tells you it's a `Book` instance (not an `NSString` instance).

Comment: How should i be able to store the bookname in a NSString?

Comment: Presumably it's an attribute of `Book`, so you call `[myBook objectForKey:@"bookName"];` (where `myBook` is the instance you get from the pointer).

Comment: The instance in this case, is that `currentUser[@"connectedBook"];`?
So i should do something like:
`PFObject *book = [currentUser[@"connectedStable"] objectForKey:@"bookName"];`?

Comment: Yes, that is the `Book` instance. Your syntax is wrong in that suggestion: `PFObject *book = currentUser[@"connectedStable"];` and separately `[book objectForKey:@"bookName"];`

Comment: When i add `[book objectForKey:@"bookName"];` i get a error message:
`'Key "bookName" has no data.  Call fetchIfNeeded before getting its value.`

Comment: So you'll need to call `fetchIfNeeded` and get the book in the completion block

Comment: Thank you so much!! I got it to work! Up-vote for you my friend!! Keep up the awesome work!!